# Dealing with multiple potential job offerings

Tags: software-industry, job-search, new-job

My situation: I just summer semester graduated in computer science (M.Sc.) from a german university and am currently applying for jobs. The market for IT graduates in Germany is good.

Based on the responses from my potential employers so far, I fear that a scenario like this is going to happen soon:

- Company A offers me a position I kind of like (8/10), starting time in a few weeks.
- Company B, with a nearly perfect job offering (10/10 for me) invites me to an interview in a few weeks time.

Obviously, I do not want to take offering A if I can have B – but B is not guaranteed. How can I deal with this situation? A knows that, legally, I could start within weeks. Delaying them would probably tell them that their offering is not the perfect one for me.

Comment: Well, what job you want? If B is really worth it you should go for it

Comment: How do you know B is the 10/10 perfect fit for you if you haven't had an interview there yet?

Comment: @Dukeling Thank you, I did not find that thread via search. As it seems, this happens quite often (it's a daisy chain of duplicates.)

Comment: If company A won't tolerate any delay, maybe they don't actually want you that bad. Regardless of other offers or lack of them, you can tell them you can't start right away, but need to start a week or two later than they wanted. It could be to get personal things in order, to quit your previous job, or whatever other reason, none of which means that you aren't serious about the offer.

Comment: @pytago consider accepting that duplicate if you found your question satisfied with the suggested dupe.

Answer (score -2):

There's no real answer anyone can give here beyond "use the best information available to you to make a decision".

You need to weigh up all your factors (how quickly could you find another job, have you any fallback / savings if you're jobless for a while, etc.) to decide whether the risk of not getting the job with company B, means it's worth turning down the offer from company A.